# Meaning of a symbol in trace

Tags: neural-networks, papers, notation

I am reading this paper [Not All Samples Are Created Equal: Deep Learning with Importance Sampling](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.00942.pdf). In the paper there is a deviation shown below.

[image]

I can understand everything except the $V$ symbol in the trace. Any help will be appreciated. Note I am only seeking to know the meaning of the symbol in this context.

Comment: It could be the variance of the random variable, but this is just a guess. I didn't read the paper. You need to check the definition of the variance and see if things are correct mathematically.